# Options -Indexes Blocking external JavaScript

Tags: html, javascript, directory-listing

I have a problem. I do not what to be able users to list in my web so I use this: `Options -Indexes` For whatever reason the external JavaScript is not loading. But when I erase this line in .htaccess
it works pretty good.

Does `Option -Indexes` means that also JavaScript cannot list in directory? If, how to enable it for JavaScript and disable for users?

Comment: That option should have no bearing on JS.  Can you post screenshots from browser develop tools showing exactly which files aren't loading?

Comment: I am calling external JavaScipt file. But the **Javascript file (.js)** os not loading. As suggested from @Steve I place an index file in the folder so now it is loading properly **(the JavaScript file)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Options -Indexes` should only prevent listing of directories that don't have an index file.  I haven't heard of the Javascript behaviour before.

There is a way around it.  Don't include the `Options -Indexes` in your .htaccess, instead include an empty index file e.g. default.html or index.php (or whatever is set up for your server) in each directory.

Comment: Thanks! For my testing example it works! But I have AngularJS that I want to be not directory listed and it have bazillions of folders. So I cannot place blank page in each. So how to prevent it with working JavaScript? Could I make PHP file that will load all .js files and then send them to HTML?